# How can I retrieve users info globally from a collection? React Native, Firebase

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

When users signup to my app they put some info and i save it in a collection in firestore like that:

```
onSignUp() {
  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then((result) => {
                firebase.firestore().collection("Patients")
                    .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
                    .set({
                        name, lastname, phonenumber, email,  pp,
                    })
                console.log(result)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }
```

How can i retrieve user's name and last name globally in `App.js` to put in the drawer menu?

App.js code:

```
export class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      loaded: false,
      fontsLoaded: false,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadFonts();
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (!user) {
        this.setState({
          loggedIn: false,
          loaded: true
        })
      } else {
        this.setState({
          loggedIn: true,
          loaded: true
        })
      }
    })
  }
```

if there's a better practice to save user's info please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Reading from Firestore is quite well documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen Did you try anything yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`redux`](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started)/[`mobX`](https://mobx.js.org/README.html) to manage global data. Once you setup you can create a global method to store data. In `redux` it will look like

SignUpAction.js

```
import { SIGNUP_REQUEST, SIGNUP_SUCCESS, SIGNUP_FAIL } from './actionType'

const onSignUpRequest = () => ({
    type: SIGNUP_REQUEST
});

const onSignUpSuccess = json => ({
    type: SIGNUP_SUCCESS,
    payload: json
});

const onSignUpFailure = error => ({
    type: SIGNUP_FAIL,
    payload: error
});
const onSignUp = (email, password, userInfo) => {
    return async (dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch(onSignUpRequest());
        try {
            let result = await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            console.log(result)
            if (!result.success)
                dispatch(onSignUpFailure(new Error('Invalid credentials.')));

            await firebase.firestore().collection("Patients")
                .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
                .set({ ...userInfo })

            dispatch(onSignUpSuccess({ ...userInfo }));
        }
        catch (error) {
            dispatch(onSignUpFailure(error));
        }
    }
}

export { onSignUp }
```

UserReducer.js

```
import { SIGNUP_REQUEST, SIGNUP_SUCCESS, SIGNUP_FAIL } from './actionType'

const initialState = {
    isFetching: false,
    errorMsg: null,
    data: null,
}

const UserData = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SIGNUP_REQUEST:
            return { ...state, isFetching: true };
        case SIGNUP_SUCCESS:
            return { ...state, isFetching: false, data: action.payload, errorMsg: '' };
        case SIGNUP_FAIL:
            return { ...state, isFetching: false, errorMsg: action.payload };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default UserData;
```

In your component, you can need

```
//...
import { onSignUp } from '@action'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

//...
componentDidMount() {
   console.log(this.props.UserData)
}

SignUp = () => {
   this.props.onSignUp(email, password, userInfo)
}

//...
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log('mapStateToProps==>', state)

    return { UserData: state.UserData }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = { onSignUp }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SignUpScreen)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use a `Provider` like this [one](https://github.com/TarikHuber/react-most-wanted/tree/master/packages/base-shell/src/providers/Auth). You can even use exactly the same code. I use it in my react/firebase app.

It's much less work than `redux` or other state management libs.